# unable to make ListView header Clickable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to make a header image placed on the top of `listView` clickable.

**records.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#efefef"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/headerImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Implementation inside activity

```
layoutInflator=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list,R.id.imageStatus, data);
        ListView listView=getListView();


        //LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        //ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);
        //listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
        View itemView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.header,listView);
        ImageView txt = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerImage);
        txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(PickupList.this,"header has been pressed", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

**Logcat**

```
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.myapp/com.android.myapp.PickupList}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:461)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:416)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at com.android.myapp.PickupList.ShowListOnUI(PickupList.java:103)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at com.android.myapp.PickupList.onCreate(PickupList.java:71)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-21 19:11:51.919: E/AndroidRuntime(22191):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Try using `this` instead of `PickupList.this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, please, do not try to inflate the View into the ListView yourself. Use the built in `addHeaderView` method of ListView that you have commented out and ***PLEASE*** [read the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) before you post...

In the docs, it clearly states that the last boolean argument determines whether or not the header view is clickable. In your code above, you have it set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

headerImage is a relative layout, you can just use the standard view class (that every view inherits from) and still use setOnClickListener method

```
    View txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerImage);
    txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // use the getContext() method from the v param
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"header has been pressed", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```